# Wordpress Home page, wrong domain url, 404 page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

First domain = beautiful.com
Second domain = ugly.com

My error is on second domain. It is placed in "beautiful.com/ugly" folder.

I configured as usual and finally my home page show 404 error and url is "beautiful.com/ugly", the direction I placed the website.

Only home page has problem and other pages go to "ugly.com/direction".
I updated Permalink, but not work.
Please share your experience to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed this problem by editing .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} beautiful.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !ugly
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ugly.com$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```